# AWS APIGateway is removing any message after & and then sending to sqs queue

Tags: amazon-sqs

I'm making a curl request to sqs queue backed by api-gateway

`curl -X POST https://ohmj5e.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod --data '{"group": "1111","url": "https://xyz.example.com/dedupe-api/?unique_id=ffff8e49b08d832d5db&email=test@gmail.com"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

However when I open the message in AWS console the message body appears to be as `https://xyz.example.com/dedupe-api/?unique_id=ffff8e49b08d832d5db`
i.e. anything after & is removed

I am using this as mapping template
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$input.body
and Request body passthough : When there are no templates defined (recommended)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here:
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-rest-api-sqs-errors

We need to encode the special characters (& or %) in the request body payload and use the mapping template
`Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$util.urlEncode($input.body)`